# Google Services - Linked App - SHA1 Issue

Tags: android, google-play-services

**Backstory**

I think I've made a mistake.

I have put together an application [Hangman](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gfaiers.hangman).

When putting together the Google Play Services to introduce achievements into the game I rushed through it all, not quite understanding everything, and [this section (3.c Specify Client ID settings)](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#c_specify_client_id_settings) I clicked Create Client with the default text of what's was already in the box.  After realising what a SHA1 is, and that it's specific to my keystore, I now realise that this is incorrect, and that's what's causing my issues in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605453/google-play-services-incorrectly-configured).

**My question**

Can I change the SHA1 of the linked application?  If not, how can I remove the linked application / change the package name of it so that I can link the application again, with the same package name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in your API console (https://console.developers.google.com/
). Login with the same account that you use for google play developer console. Go to Credentials section , click on the OAuth Client ID and change the SHA1 key.

Comment: I'd already done this, then for some reason I had 2 Hangman games on there one day, decided to delete one of them, looks like I deleted the one that I needed! Thanks!